# How to set content-type of .Net WebClient::UploadString()?

Tags: .net, c++

I am using .net in C++.

How to set http header content-type if using .Net `WebClient::UploadString()` or `WebClient::UploadData()`?

Basically, I want to send some Unicode string to the HTTP server (using Mongoose), and the server will then decode the data received base on the content-type field. Is there another alternative or any better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) member as part of the WebClient class. You can set the Content-Type header by adding it to the Headers collection:

```
myWebClient->Headers->Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Subsquent calls to UploadString (or other methods that make requests) the header will be sent along with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Call `WebClient::GetWebRequest()`—it returns an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest) object with a `ContentType` property. You then pass it to `WebClient::GetWebResponse()` to send the request.